# Detecting RTP packet loss

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, wireshark, rtp

For this, I wrote a simple python script which connect to a multicast ip and port, read some data from the socket and extracts some bytes. These extracted bytes are actually the sequence number from the RTP header. Here is the code:

```
import struct

MULTICAST_IP = '236.0.1.199'
PORT = 9101  

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', PORT))
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, socket.inet_aton(MULTICAST_IP) + socket.inet_aton('0.0.0.0'))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(2048)
    sequence_number = struct.unpack('!H', data[2:4])[0]
    print(f"RTP packet received, Sequence Number: {sequence_number}")
```

All good so far. Now I introduce a 10% packet loss using:

```
tc qdisc add dev wlp0s20f3 root netem loss 10%
```

With this I expected that the some of the RTP sequence numbers may be missing from the code output because of the dropped packets, but there is no missing packets as per this output.
To verify if the packet drop actually works, I configured wireshark to read from the same multicast and somehow it detects the missing packets i.e there are some missing sequence numbers (seen when the packet is decoded as RTP). To cross-verify I deleted the tc qdisc rule to remove 10% packet loss and wireshark didn't show any missing packets.

following are the questions:

1. Is this the correct way to simulate packet loss over multicast ?
2. If yes, how is wireshark able to detect it and if there is anything extra needed to add in my script to detect the RTP packet loss?

Any help will be appreciated.